# Is there any way to get the group by data with latest entry in sequelize typescript

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have (almost) identical multiple rows in a table in which `createdAt` is different.
I am using sequelize typescript as ORM for mysql data.
Is there a way how I can use group by on 2 columns of the table lets say colA, colB but get the latest entry in that group?
an equivalent MySQL query for this would be :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM tableName
    group by tableName.colA,
    tableName.colB
);
```

But I don't want to use id as max, and how can I get it in sequelize typescript?

With the normal group by col such as:

```
MyModel.findAll({
    where: {
       createdAt: { [Op.lt]: today }
    },
    group: ['colA','colB']
})
```

I was able to retrieve the grouped columns' first createdAt entry whereas I want the last entry.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Plesae try with `order by`

```
MyModel.findAll({
    where: {
       createdAt: { [Op.lt]: today }
    },
    order : [['createdAt','DESC']],
    group: ['colA','colB']
})
```